# Google assistant module doesn’t show my calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-assistant-sdk

I have configured google assistant in my raspberry pi as mentioned in the below link
https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/run-sample

In the google action console, i have given permission to all the activities.

But when I tried assessing google calendar through google assistant in my raspberry pi, Google assistant module doesn’t show my calendar anymore.

It says " First I’ll need your permission to give Personals Results. You can make that change in Google Assistant Settings on your phone."

Then I receive a notification on my phone to allow permission
[image]

As soon as I click on “Personal results” to allow permission on phone, the app crashes. I have tried 2 different phones but same thing happens.

So I deleted token & credential file and used a new credentials (auth), allowed all permission but it still gives me the same message when I ask for my personal results such as calendar.

Has something changed? Could someone help to solve this issue?